# Why has my daily quota increased from 10k to 2 billion?

Tags: support, api-v2.2, quota

I'm using the Stack Exchange API with an access token and API key, and I was just checking my remaining quota. According to the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle), this should be a number (somewhat) lower than 10,000, which is consistent what I've seen in the past.

However, to my surprise, today it's more like the 32-bit integer maximum:

[image]

This happens for multiple API routes, not just for /sites. I do get occasional backoffs, which I obey to. What's going on here? Santa Exchange giving out unlimited quota as Christmas presents? It does not matter which IP address I'm calling the API from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After re-investigating my code, I realized what was going on here. For this particular project I wasn't using the API key and access token of my own application; I'm using the ones I sniffed from the communication between the ([now discontinued](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/295232)) Stack Exchange iOS app and the API. That has an unlimited quota, it seems. Interestingly enough, the Android app has the regular 10k quota.